# Android: Incoming call screen contains no Answer & reject options - TelecomManager & Connection Service

Tags: android, voip

I'm building a voip app and will be using Android's incoming call UI. I've successfully registered a phoneAccount using the **TelecomManager** and managed to get `addNewIncomingCall` working.

The problem is that when the phone is locked I get the incoming call UI but NO actions to answer or dismiss the call. [image]

In the other hand, if the phone is not locked I still get the incoming call UI but it DOES contain actions to answer or dismiss the call. [image]

Any ideas as to what might be happening?

I can attach code if needed. 
But basically I'm following this android's documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html

Comment: Hey @riswady29, can you please share the code how you are doing this. The documentation regarding this is not clear to me. Can you point me in the right direction. I am also looking forward to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Can you share how you have registered a phoneAccount using the TelecomManager?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [test implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/services/Telecomm/+/master/testapps/) of these APIs in the AOSP repository.  Take a look at how the TestConnectionService does things.

Be forewarned, the CTS test coverage for these APIs was not complete in M (or even N for that matter), so its possible that OEMs do not fully support them in their intended manner.  Starting in O the CTS test coverage has been improved so OEM compatibility should improve.

Comment: And Samsung, in particular, is problematic.  Make sure you test both with and without One UI.  And when I say "test" what I mean is "notice how your code breaks on Samsung devices, and there's nothing you can do about it."